# Need help in creating an equation of meeting quality

Tags: regression, time-series

I want to create an equation that consists of two independent variables "duration" and "data_transferred", and one dependent variable "meeting_quality"

This is what I want:

meeting_quality would be good, if more data is transferred in less duration.

meeting_quality would be bad, if less data is transferred in more duration.

What should be the equation presentation of above sentence? Thanks in advance.

In fact, I want to use the values above equation in regression analysis. I would really be grateful for any further advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From you description, you want to measure`data_trasferred` per unit of `duration` (time) and term it as `meeting_quality`. However, you are more interested in categorical value of `meeting_quality` rather than specific numerical value.

Numeric value of `meeting_quality` would be `data_transferred`/`duration`. To categorise your meeting quality you need to specify a `cut-off` below which the quality is low.
Then the categorical value of `meeting_quality`=int((`data_transferred`/`duration`)/`cut-off`).

Zero would signify low quality whereas positive integer would mean high quality.

Comment: Thank you. I like your suggestion of introducing cut offs.